# having a counter for rock paper scissors

Tags: javascript, arrays

My instructor for my class instructed us how to create a rock paper scissors game using HTML, Javascript, and CSS.

```js
//Array that will store the actual images to be used
var pics=new Array();

var winHud = document.getElementById("extra-ammo");
var tieHud = document.getElementById("current-ammo");
var losHud = document.getElementById("current-ammo");

var winSpan = document.getElementById('You Win!')
var tieSpan = document.getElementById('It\'s A Tie!')
var losSpan = document.getElementById('You Lose')

var win = 0;
var tie = 0;
var loss = 0;

pics [0]="images/rock.jpg";
pics [1]="images/paper.jpg";
pics [2]="images/scissors.jpg";
pics [3]="images/lizard.jpg";
pics [4]="images/spock.jpg";

//Array that will store the highlighted images
var pics2=new Array();

pics2 [0]="images/rock2.jpg";
pics2 [1]="images/paper2.jpg";
pics2 [2]="images/scissors2.jpg";
pics2 [3]="images/lizard2.jpg";
pics2 [4]="images/spock2.jpg";

//Array for the player ID
var pId=new Array("rock_p","paper_p","scissors_p","lizard_p","spock_p");

//Array for the computer ID
var cId=new Array();

cId[0]="rock_c";
cId[1]="paper_c";
cId[2]="scissors_c";
cId[3]="lizard_c";
cId[4]="spock_c";



//Function that will swap the images to the highlighted ones

function swap(id,image) {
 document.getElementById(id).src=image;
 
}//end swap

//function that plays the game
function play(id) {
 swap(pId[0],pics[0]);
 swap(pId[1],pics[1]);
 swap(pId[2],pics[2]);
 swap(pId[3],pics[3]);
 swap(pId[4],pics[4]);
 
 swap(cId[0],pics[0]);
 swap(cId[1],pics[1]);
 swap(cId[2],pics[2]);
 swap(cId[3],pics[3]);
 swap(cId[4],pics[4]);
 
 //variable that will store what we pick
 var p_choice=id;
 
 //variable that will store what the computer picks
 var c_choice=id; 
 
 //math.floor rounds down the choices that the computer is going to make
 var c_choice=Math.floor(Math.random()*4.9);
 swap(pId[p_choice],pics2[p_choice]);
 swap(cId[c_choice],pics2[c_choice]);
 
 //determines who wins or loses
 switch(p_choice) {
  case 0:
  if (c_choice==0){
   alert("Tie:\nOh Rock you too then!");
  }
  else if(c_choice==1) {
   alert("Lose:\nPaper covers Rock")
  }
  else if(c_choice==2) {
   alert("Win:\nRock crushes Scissors")
  }
  else if(c_choice==3) {
   alert("Win:\nRock crushes Lizard")
  }
  else if(c_choice==4) {
   alert("Lose:\nSpock vaporizes Rock")
  }
  break;

  case 1:
  if (c_choice==1){
   alert("Tie:\nTwo pieces of paper stack up against each other");
  }
  else if(c_choice==0) {
   alert("Win:\nPaper covers Rock")
  }
  else if(c_choice==2) {
   alert("Lose:\nScissors cuts Paper")
  }
  else if(c_choice==3) {
   alert("Lose:\nLizard eats Paper")
  }
  else if(c_choice==4) {
   alert("Win:\nPaper disproves Spock")
  }
  break;
  
  case 2:
  if (c_choice==2){
   alert("Tie:\nThis is unacceptable! Unless you're a lesbian");
  }
  else if(c_choice==0) {
   alert("Lose:\nRock crushes Scissors")
  }
  else if(c_choice==1) {
   alert("Win:\nScissors cuts Paper")
  }
  else if(c_choice==3) {
   alert("Win:\nScissors decapitates Lizard")
  }
  else if(c_choice==4) {
   alert("Lose:\nSpock smashes Scissors")
  }
  break;
  
  case 3:
  if (c_choice==3){
   alert("Tie:\nTwo Lizards begin mating");
  }
  else if(c_choice==0) {
   alert("Lose:\nRock crushes Lizard")
  }
  else if(c_choice==1) {
   alert("Win:\nLizard eats Paper")
  }
  else if(c_choice==2) {
   alert("Lose:\nScissors decapitates Lizard")
  }
  else if(c_choice==4) {
   alert("Win:\nLizard poisons Spock")
  }
  break;
  case 4:
  if (c_choice==4){
   alert("Tie:\nOne of us is going to have to give up Spock");
  }
  else if(c_choice==0) {
   alert("Win:\nSpock vaporizes Rock")
  }
  else if(c_choice==1) {
   alert("Lose:\nPaper disproves Spock")
  }
  else if(c_choice==2) {
   alert("Win:\nSpock crushes Scissors")
  }
  else if(c_choice==3) {
   alert("Lose:\nLizard poisons Spock")
  }
  break;
 }
}//end play function
```

```css
/* CSS Document */

header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5cc6bc;
}

footer {
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #5cc6bc;
    border-top: 1px solid #5cc6bc;
}

img {
    border: 2px solid #5cc6bc;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: helvetica;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5cc6bc;
    font-family: Arial, helvetica;
}

h3 {
}

h4 {
}

h5 {
}

h6 {
    font-family: cambria;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 725px;
    background-color: #16143c;
    background-image: url(../images/LSExpansion.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px 110px;
    background-size: 960px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#optionsncounter {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 467px auto auto 0px;
}

.player {
    background-color: #16143c;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 290px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.counter {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #16143c;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 220px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.computer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #16143c;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 290px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

#wins {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5cc6bc;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
}

#ties {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5cc6bc;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#losses {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5cc6bc;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!--Ledoux, Steven R. GDS111.01 RPS-->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rock,Paper,Scissors,Lizard,Spock | Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rps.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 <header>
 <h1>Rock - Paper - Scissors - Lizard - Spock</h1>
 <h6>By: Dr. Sheldon Cooper</h6>
 </header>
 <span id="win">Win!</span>
 <span id="tie">Tie!</span>
 <span id="tie">Lost!</span>
  <div id="optionsncounter"><!--ONC container-->
   <div class="player">
    <!-- p = player-->
       <h2 class="title">Player</h2>
    <img src="images/rock.jpg" id="rock_p" onclick="play(0);"/>
    <img src="images/paper.jpg" id="paper_p" onclick="play(1);"/>
    <img src="images/scissors.jpg" id="scissors_p" onclick="play(2);"/>
    <img src="images/lizard.jpg" id="lizard_p" onclick="play(3);"/>
    <img src="images/spock.jpg" id="spock_p" onclick="play(4);"/>
            </div><!-- /.player -->
   <div class="computer">
    <!-- c = computer-->
       <h2 class="title">Computer</h2>
    <img src="images/rock.jpg" id="rock_c"/>
    <img src="images/paper.jpg" id="paper_c"/>
    <img src="images/scissors.jpg" id="scissors_c"/>
    <img src="images/lizard.jpg" id="lizard_c"/>
    <img src="images/spock.jpg" id="spock_c"/>
            </div><!-- /.computer -->
   <div class="counter">
    <!-- c = computer-->
       <h2 class="title">Results</h2>
    <img src="images/CounterBG.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/CounterBG.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/CounterBG.jpg"/>
            </div><!-- wtl = -->
  </div><!--ONC container-->
    <footer>&copy; Copyright 2015, Steven Ledoux</footer>
</div><!-- /#container -->
</body>
</html>
```

I expanded it with Lizard and Spock. My intent is to get the "Wins-Ties-Loses" counter to work first, but I am not sure how to get one to work. I saw other ways on this site for an RPS counter, but I am unsure how to get it to work in my JavaScript code. Here is also a jsfiddle link, jsfiddle.net/kvwygeen

Comment: Please use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) in future questions. I created this one for you: http://jsfiddle.net/kvwygeen/ .

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems to be a user preference because I get people saying use the snippet or send jsfiddle/jsbin. I will work on coding this and seeing how it works.

Comment: I'm answering your question right now, don't worry. Your best bet is to provide both versions, as it's, as you mentioned, a pretty personal preference.

Comment: @StevenLedoux Post the relevant snippet here, and a link to a fiddle. The easier you make your question to understand and answer, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a global counting variable, something like this outside your method:

```
var counter = {computer: 0, user: 0};
```

Then in your `switch` statement, just add something like this:

```
// ...
case 0:
    switch (c_choice) {
        // i slightly modified your code to be a little more readable, just look at the fiddle
        case 4:
            alert("Lose:\nSpock vaporizes Rock");
            counter.computer += 1; // increment the counter
            break;
    }
```

Then at the end, just update the counter display (which you have to add at the desired position; give it an `id="your-id"` attribute). Then simply set its text by

```
document.getElementById("your-id").setInnerHTML = counter.computer; // or any other value
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kvwygeen/1/)'s the fiddle I updated.

You might also want to check out [enums](https://github.com/zhaber/symbol-enum) in JavaScript, so you can use terms like `case SPOCK:` to improve your code even further.

Comment: I apologize if this sounds like a silly question, but what would you recommend for a "tie" for javascript, I can guess that the computer would add to the loss counter, and the user adds to the win counter.

Comment: Don't add anything for a tie if the counters represent wins.

Comment: Again, thanks for the help, I will get to work on this.